# how would i display multiple data from an sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i cant seem to display multiple  data from my database. only one  data from my database gets printed.

DatabaseHelper:

```
    public Cursor returnData2(String text, String look){
    String data;
    String where = "_column LIKE '"+look+"%'";


    Cursor c = myDataBase.query("translate_metadata", null, where, null, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){

       c.moveToNext();
    }
    return c;

}
```

activity:

```
    String inputtext = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputKey)).getText().toString();
            String lowerinput = inputtext.toLowerCase();
            data = myDbHelper.returnData2("databasename",lowerinput);
             if(data.moveToFirst()){
                 rdata = data.getString(1);
                 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.keyList)).setText(""+rdata.toString()+"\n");

             }

            myDbHelper.close(); 
        }
```

sorry if  its confusing. but i need the help. any suggestion will do. thanks

Comment: In your Activity you are not looping through your cursor. you are just accessing it once. Use a loop and let me know the result.

Comment: Check this [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextView.append` to show all data in single TextView:

```
TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.keyList);
if(data.moveToFirst()){
       rdata = data.getString(1);
       txtView.append(""+rdata.toString()+"\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your take it and try this

```
public Cursor returnData2(String text, String look){
    String data;
    String where = "_column LIKE '"+look+"%'";


    Cursor c = myDataBase.query("translate_metadata", null, where, null, null, null, null);

    myDbHelper.close(); 

    return c;

}

   TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.keyList);
   String inputtext = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputKey)).getText().toString();
                String lowerinput = inputtext.toLowerCase();
                data = myDbHelper.returnData2("databasename",lowerinput);

                if(data.moveToFirst()){
                 while(!data.isAfterLast()){
                  rdata = data.getString(1);
                  txtView.append(""+rdata.toString()+"\n");

                  c.moveToNext();
                }
              }

          data.close();
```